# When trying to paste using FormulaR1C1 in excel macro, cell is filled empty

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I used "record macro" to get the following formula. when I try to paste them back into the cells, they are not working. no formula gets inserted into the cells

my formula as follows

```
Dim schedsheet as Worksheet
Set schedsheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
schedstartrow = 15
schedendrow = 134
schedsheet.Range("Q" & schedstartrow, "Q" & schedendrow).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-13]=""DES"","""",IFERROR(INDEX(C67,MATCH(SUMIFS(C63,C66,RC[25],C65,RC[-9]),C63,0)),""""))"
schedsheet.Range("T" & schedstartrow, "T" & schedendrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(R[1]C9:R[1000]C9,MATCH(RC[-10],R[1]C[-10]:R[1000]C[-10],0)),"""")"
```

Comment: Do you have `On Error Resume Next` earlier in your code?

Comment: Unable to reproduce based on the provided information.

Comment: Hi - for some reason excel does not even insert a formula into the cell. i dont want to "resume next"

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Is there an blanket `On Error Resume Next` earlier in your code? And, based on what you provided, I'm unable to reproduce this.

Comment: I've made a small update to the code which hopefully should help. yes, i believe there is a blanket on error resume next in the code

Comment: First step, remove the blanket `On Error Resume Next`, rerun, then report back on any error messages.

Comment: i have resovled this - i was inaccurately linking to a wrong sheet. thank you for your help.